# Html.DropDownFor Binding Issue in IE8 Related to CSS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

All,

I'm having this strange issue in IE8 regarding binding model data to an Html.DropDownListFor element with a CSS width attribute applied.

I have a parent dropdown list that when changed causes a data look up, and then the model with the new data is supposed to bind to a child dropdown list.

In IE8, if I try and add a CSS width attribute in either the Html.DropListFor element or via Javascript attribute, the dropdownlist won't bind to the new data in the model.

If I have now width attribute, it works fine even in IE8.

Code:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EnrollmentToBatchDataContract.Spl, new SelectList(Model.SPLs, "Text", "Value"), "-- Please choose an SPL --", new {id="ddlSPL", name="ddlSPL"})
```

JS function:

```
  function updateSPL(data) {
    $('#ddlSPL >option').remove();
    $('#ddlSPL').append($('<option></option>').html(""));
        for (var x = 0; x < data.SPLs.length; x++) {
            $('#ddlSPL').append($('<option value="' + data.SPLs[x].Value + '"> ' + data.SPLs[x].Text + '</option>').html(data.SPLs[x].Text));
        }
};
```

I know that the model is being updated and passed into the JS function. I tested that the expected values are in the data object.

Also this works correctly in Chrome and FF.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Try this, In your `Html.DropdownListFor` method pass the `id` and `name` parameter like this `new {@id="ddlSPL", @name="ddlSPL"}`

Comment: @ is needed for class because class is a C# keyword. id and name are not. I don't see width in your code.